# como validar para nome não receber numeros e nem caracteres especiais c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Como faço pra fazer uma validação no atributo nome onde ele não permita números e nem caracteres especiais ?

fiz assim porém não está funcionando

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo nome é obrigatório!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Limite máximo de 50 caracteres e limite minimo de 2 caracteres")]
[MinLength(2)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{2,50}+$", ErrorMessage ="Números e caracteres especiais não são permitidos no nome.")]
public string Nome { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa expressão está inválida, e parece que você tentou incluir nela um limite de caracteres, algo que não faz muito sentido sendo que você já utiliza os atributos `MaxLength` e `MinLength`.

Tenta utilizar essa expressão para permitir apenas espaços e letras.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"
```

Agora para fazer a validação das propriedades, você utiliza `DataAnnotations`.

Segue um método que faz uma validação completa.

```
public static IEnumerable<ValidationResult> GetErrors(object model)
{
   var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
   var context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
   Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, result, true);
   return result;
}
```

Onde o parâmetro `model` seria a sua classe.

Isso não impede que o valor seja atribuído a propriedade, ela apenas verifica se a sua classe modelo está valida ou não e informa os erros conforme você definiu nos atributos.

Sugiro que você veja [esse post](http://www.macoratti.net/13/12/c_vdda.htm) sobre validação de dados com DataAnnotations